# Two sample quantile-quantile plot in Python

Tags: python, quantiles

Suppose I have two samples from unknown distributions, and I want to produce a quantile-quantile plot of one against the other. What's the easiest way to do this in Python?

There is [scipy.stats.probplot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html), and something similar in [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html), but both produce a q-q plot of data versus some predefined distribution, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple one-off solution:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Setup
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)  # Seed RNG for replicability
n = 100  # Number of samples to draw

# Generate data
x = rng.normal(size=n)  # Sample 1: X ~ N(0, 1)
y = rng.standard_t(df=5, size=n)  # Sample 2: Y ~ t(5)

# Quantile-quantile plot
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(np.sort(x), np.sort(y))
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

which produces

[image: qqplot]

Better yet, you can modularize this code by writing a q-q plot function, something like the following:

```py
import numbers

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def qqplot(x, y, quantiles=None, interpolation='nearest', ax=None, rug=False,
           rug_length=0.05, rug_kwargs=None, **kwargs):
    """Draw a quantile-quantile plot for `x` versus `y`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x, y : array-like
        One-dimensional numeric arrays.

    ax : matplotlib.axes.Axes, optional
        Axes on which to plot. If not provided, the current axes will be used.

    quantiles : int or array-like, optional
        Quantiles to include in the plot. This can be an array of quantiles, in
        which case only the specified quantiles of `x` and `y` will be plotted.
        If this is an int `n`, then the quantiles will be `n` evenly spaced
        points between 0 and 1. If this is None, then `min(len(x), len(y))`
        evenly spaced quantiles between 0 and 1 will be computed.

    interpolation : {‘linear’, ‘lower’, ‘higher’, ‘midpoint’, ‘nearest’}
        Specify the interpolation method used to find quantiles when `quantiles`
        is an int or None. See the documentation for numpy.quantile().

    rug : bool, optional
        If True, draw a rug plot representing both samples on the horizontal and
        vertical axes. If False, no rug plot is drawn.

    rug_length : float in [0, 1], optional
        Specifies the length of the rug plot lines as a fraction of the total
        vertical or horizontal length.

    rug_kwargs : dict of keyword arguments
        Keyword arguments to pass to matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline() and
        matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline() when drawing rug plots.

    kwargs : dict of keyword arguments
        Keyword arguments to pass to matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter() when drawing
        the q-q plot.
    """
    # Get current axes if none are provided
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    if quantiles is None:
        quantiles = min(len(x), len(y))

    # Compute quantiles of the two samples
    if isinstance(quantiles, numbers.Integral):
        quantiles = np.linspace(start=0, stop=1, num=int(quantiles))
    else:
        quantiles = np.atleast_1d(np.sort(quantiles))
    x_quantiles = np.quantile(x, quantiles, interpolation=interpolation)
    y_quantiles = np.quantile(y, quantiles, interpolation=interpolation)

    # Draw the rug plots if requested
    if rug:
        # Default rug plot settings
        rug_x_params = dict(ymin=0, ymax=rug_length, c='gray', alpha=0.5)
        rug_y_params = dict(xmin=0, xmax=rug_length, c='gray', alpha=0.5)

        # Override default setting by any user-specified settings
        if rug_kwargs is not None:
            rug_x_params.update(rug_kwargs)
            rug_y_params.update(rug_kwargs)

        # Draw the rug plots
        for point in x:
            ax.axvline(point, **rug_x_params)
        for point in y:
            ax.axhline(point, **rug_y_params)

    # Draw the q-q plot
    ax.scatter(x_quantiles, y_quantiles, **kwargs)
```

This can be used as follows:

```py
# Setup
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)  # Seed RNG for replicability

# Example 1: samples of the same length
n = 100  # Number of samples to draw
x = rng.normal(size=n)  # Sample 1: X ~ N(0, 1)
y = rng.standard_t(df=5, size=n)  # Sample 2: Y ~ t(5)

# Draw quantile-quantile plot
plt.figure()
qqplot(x, y, c='r', alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Two samples of the same length')
plt.show()
plt.close()

# Example 2: samples of different lengths
n_u = 50  # Number of U samples to draw
n_v = 100  # Number of V samples to draw
u = rng.normal(size=n_u)  # Sample 1: U ~ N(0, 1)
v = rng.standard_t(df=5, size=n_v)  # Sample 2: V ~ t(5)

# Draw quantile-quantile plot
plt.figure()
qqplot(u, v, c='r', alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
plt.xlabel('U')
plt.ylabel('V')
plt.title('Two samples of different lengths')
plt.show()
plt.close()

# Draw quantile-quantile plot with rug plot
plt.figure()
qqplot(u, v, c='r', alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k', rug=True)
plt.xlabel('U')
plt.ylabel('V')
plt.title('Two samples of different lengths, with rug plot')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

which produces

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Here is a somewhat more general thing (works for different-length inputs) (feel free to incorporate it into your answer, I don't have enough rep here to edit).

     def qqplot(x, y, numquant=None, ax=None, **kwargs):
           if ax is None:
              ax = plt.gca()
        if numquant is None:
           numquant = min(len(x), len(y))
        x1=np.quantile(x, np.linspace(0, 1, numquant))
        y1=np.quantile(y, np.linspace(0, 1, numquant))

        ax.scatter(np.sort(x1), np.sort(y1), **kwargs)

Comment: @IgorRivin excellent improvement! I updated the answer with a modification of your idea and a couple other features.

Comment: Very nice! Maybe this should be incorporated into the "canon"....

Comment: Yes, really nice post How do you choose `df=5` - i.e. why did you use `5` in `Sample 2: Y ~ t(5)`?

Comment: @edesz it is an arbitrary choice made for the example. I could have chosen any df for the purpose of showing how the qq plot function works

Comment: @IgorRivin Is there a way to accelerate `np.quantile` function? Using `interpolation` function argument slows down the process especially when `len(x)` and `len(y)` are more than a million samples.

Answer (score 0):

It might increase your chances of getting a useful answer if you told us
your reason for wanting to make such a plot. It will probably
be easiest to make a useful plot if your two samples are of the same size.

One possibility is to sort the data and plot one sorted sample against the other.  (I'm using R, but I guess you can make sense of the simple code.)

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(1000, 100, 10);  y = rexp(1000, 1/100)
plot(sort(x), sort(y), pch=20)
```

[image]

If you have a reasonable guess what the two distributions are (including parameters), you might try transforming each sample by the CDF of its
distribution. If your guess is good, you should get (nearly) a straight line.

```
x1 = pnorm(sort(x), 100, 10)
y1 = pexp(sort(y), 1/100)
plot(x1, y1, pch=20)
```

[image]

If you're trying to see whether the two samples may have come from the same distribution (and in R, the sample sizes are equal and less than 5000), you 
might use a Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test. (For my `x` and `y`, the answer is No.)

```
ks.test(x, y)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x and y
D = 0.521, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Comment: "Why" is complicated, but in my case I am certain that the distributions are not the same. I would like to know that they are qualitatively of the same "kind". For example, if I look at the eigenvalue spacings of a random hermitian matrix and a random symmetric matrix, the distribution of the spacings will NOT be the same, but is kind of similar, and the q-q plot may capture this.